# Vue.js unit:test : Is there any way to mock a Vee-Validate validator plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vee-validate

I am testing a form component, all fields are validated with `vee-validate`
Currently I a injecting in my wrapper mount a validator

```
import VeeValidate from "vee-validate";

Vue.use(VeeValidate, { errorBagName: "errors" });

describe("ContactForm.vue", () => {
 const v = new VeeValidate.Validator();

 beforeEach(() => {
  options = {
        sync: false,
        provide: () => ({
          $validator: v
        })
 };
 wrapper = shallowMount(ContactForm, options);
});
```

the `$validator` has some functions like :  `init(), localize(), validateAll() , reset(), ...` that I could bypass in some of my tests

Is there anyway to mock such `validator` with `Jest` functions ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use stubs of your functions using [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) ? They mentioned that on [vue test utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper-array/#setmethods-methods) with `setMethods`.

It could look like:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import ContactForm from './ContactForm.vue'

const wrapper = mount(ContactForm)
const submit = wrapper.find('button')
const validateStub = sinon.stub()

allInputs.setMethods({ validateAll: validateStub })
submit.trigger('click')
expect(validateStub.called).toBe(true)
```

So you would be able to know if the `validateAll` method is called when you submit the form for example. Or you could try asking on [github/VeeValidate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues)